# Is there a way to check if Apollo has data cached before trying to call the cache?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I need to find out if Apollo has data cached before trying to call a query for that data from the cache.

This code throws the `"Invariant Violation: Can't find field ...... on object"` error if we haven't already called the USER_QUERY. However I don't have a way to check if we've ever called it.

```
const cachedData = client.readQuery({
   query: USER_QUERY,
   variables: queryVariables,
});
```

My problem is I don't know how to check if we've cached data or not before calling any cache.

Answer (score 2):

you can wrap the `client.readQuery` portion with try catch as suggest [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/1701)  and [here](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/1776) ;)

```
try {
  const cachedData = client.readQuery({
     query: USER_QUERY,
     variables: queryVariables,
  });
} catch(e) {
  // maybe you can safely swallow the error
}
```